# TypeError(str(ret) +”is not valid value for expected return type integer”)

Tags: python, equation

I’ve been trying to do a problem on leetcode(29) and i submit my answer but it gives me this error. Here’s the code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def divide(self, dividend, divisor):
        """
        :type dividend: int
        :type divisor: int
        :rtype: int
        """
dividend = input()
divisor = input()
if -2^31 <= dividend and divisor != None and divisor<= 2^31 - 1:
 result = dividend/divisor
else:
 print("Invalid")
 exit()
print(result)
```

It should give me the int of the division.

Comment: If it's expecting you to return `result`, you're `print`ing it instead of returning it. Also note that `^` isn't exponentiation is Python. You want `**`.